# Error in stringWithXMLTag

Tags: objective-c

My app crashes on the line:

```
NSString *test=[NSString stringWithXMLTag:@"name" andValue:@"NameTest"];
```

Comment: This is not a question, please elaborate or it will get closed. That is obviously a category method and without an error message (or possible warnings you are ignoring) it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: You surely have precisions to give us on that...

Comment: Looks fine to me.  What is the error?  What is stringWithXMLTag?

Comment: Where exactly did you get this piece of code?

Comment: Can you post the code to stringWithXMLTag?

Comment: looks like some kind of category on `NSString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you aren't including the **NSString+stringWithXMLTag.h** file.  Consequently, your app will not recognize the `stringWithXMLTag:andValue` selector.

Add this to the top of your file that receives the crash:

```
#import "NSString+stringWithXMLTag.h"
```

This, of course, assumes you have that file in your project (and any of its dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

This error is saying that the [**`NSString`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html) class does not have a selector (method) named `stringWithXMLTag:andValue`.

Comment: ok,thanks, but what is the solution??

Comment: @user823238 - Which library are you using ?

Comment: SDK authorize.net, in the SDK error occurs.